# encoding string to utf in python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm fairly confused about encodings in python. I have the following string.

```
s = "Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea"
```

I want to make it a unicode string so that it will display properly. The following works:

```
t = u"Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea"

print t
```

The output is "Café/Coffee/Tea"

However if instead I try

```
r = unicode(s)
```

I get the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)"

I'm not even trying to display the unicode string to the console when I do this (what I recently learned is called a 'heisenbug'). But it seems my console can print unicode so I really don't understand the issue.

This is python 2.7 if that matters.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html try looking in here.

Comment: that string (bytes) is already encoded.  you need to `.decode` it to get a unicode object.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to Python 3 if nothing holds you back to Python 2 - you'd have much less confusion with Unicode there.

Comment: yeah. i'd like to switch to python 3, but i'm using the anaconda distribution of python... and that's still on 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
>>> "Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea".decode('iso-8859-1')
```

---

Though I suggest that if possible use UTF-8 everywhere for Unicode encoding.

Comment: Hem, I do not know what is the charset you're using, it is not latin-1; \xf1 in Latin 1 is `ñ`

Comment: I don't think 'iso-8859-1' is the right encoding.  That will give you ñ instead of é.

Comment: é is `\xe9`, but ñ is `\xf1`

Comment: @Antti. I made a mistake pasting that in. Should have been "Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea". Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, @Aaron, `\xf1` is never é in any code page, just tested.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I have tested that too.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the encoding of your source file and you can write the Unicode characters directly in the file:

```
# coding: utf8
s = 'Café/Coffee/Tea'
print repr(s)
print s
t = u'Café/Coffee/Tea'
print t
```

Output (Note my *console* uses encoding `cp437`):

```
'Caf\xc3\xa9/Coffee/Tea'
Caf├⌐/Coffee/Tea
Café/Coffee/Tea
```

The first line is a byte string.  It will be in the source encoding. The second line does not print correctly since UTF-8 was sent to a code page 437 terminal.  Python knows to encode the Unicode string to the console encoding, so the 3rd line prints correctly.

Here the source is declared and saved in a different encoding.  Note printing Unicode is still correct:

```
# coding: iso-8859-1
s = 'Café/Coffee/Tea'
print repr(s)
print s
t = u'Café/Coffee/Tea'
print t
```

Output:

```
'Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea'
CafΘ/Coffee/Tea
Café/Coffee/Tea
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode that string using "Latin-1' , to Unicode.

```
>>> s = "Caf\xe9/Coffee/Tea"
>>> r = unicode(s, 'Latin-1')
>>> print r

Café/Coffee/Tea
```

Answer (score 0):

`unicode(bytestring)` functions tries to decode the input bytestring using the default encoding on Python 2 (`'ascii'`). There are bytes outside ascii range and therefore it fails.

Note `"\xf1"` and `u"\xf1"` are *very* different on Python 2. The former is a bytestring, the latter is a Unicode string:

```
>>> "\xf1".decode('cp866')
u'\u0451'
>>> "\xf1".decode('cp437')                                                                                
u'\xb1'
>>> "\xf1".decode('latin-1')                                                                              
u'\xf1'
>>> u"\xf1".encode('cp866')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp866.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> u"\xf1".encode('cp437')
'\xa4'
>>> u"\xf1".encode('latin-1')
'\xf1'
```

[There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). If you want to convert bytes into text; you should specify the character encoding.